# How to create an html header for every file in a project using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, header, conventions

I'm working on a simple GitHub pages site using HTML and javascript. Since pages do not offer support for PHP or SSI includes for an HTML header from a separate HTML file, I need to write a script which will create the header images an establish the links in the menu ribbon.

Suppose for the sake of understanding this website is composed of three files whose paths are:

```
root/index.html
root/A/pageA.html
root/B/pageB.html
```

The header should have a link to each of these files.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to use these in all files:

```
<a href='https://somewhere.something/index.html'>Index</a>
<a href='https://somewhere.something/A/pageA.html'>A</a>
<a href='https://somewhere.something/B/pageB.html'>B</a>
```

I just was unsure if this is good practice!

If there is a way to accomplish the same effect which is more conventional I would love to hear it.

Comment: jQuery's `load()` method can let you include header and menu in each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below SO snippet not works, but here is working [example](http://misja.mahajana.pl/) - click on left menu, look into page source)

```js
async function load(url) {
  let html = await (await fetch(url)).text();
  pageBody.innerHTML = html;
}

let page = location.search.substr(1) || 'index';

load(page + '.html');
```

```html
<h1>My site</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?index" >Main</a></li>
  <li><a href="?A/pageA" >A</a></li>
  <li><a href="?B/pageB" >B</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="pageBody">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **[HTML Imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)**.

The `<head>` section that you place on each page would reference a single import file:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/import.html">
</head>
```

With your import file containing what you want to load into each page's `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Note that the import file should not contain `<head></head>` tags itself, merely the *contents*.

Comment: This is seems useful, but I'm not sure it answers my question. I was asking for the most appropriate way to change the href attributes of links in html files in subfolders, sorry if that was unclear